# Export a group of animations done by code as a video file

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, avfoundation, core-animation

I have a group of data which contains image,video,animations,text like that...
I want combine that datas and make it as a Video.by coding i have created a one minute animation like a video.Is there any way export it as a video? if it can't, is there any useful method for creating a video ? and one more thing, is it possible to use external video plugins in Xcode ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool`. See [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avvideocompositioncoreanimationtool) for more info.
[Here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/30200/avfoundation-tutorial-adding-overlays-and-animations-to-videos)
you can find an example of usage.